# Wrapper Component showing different navigation on different pages

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make my page flexible to show different navigation bars depending on the page I'm on. When I run the page with the code presented below it shows the different navs as they should, but the actualRouteComponent is not showing the content of the route component eg. FrontpageRoute, BookRoute.

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Mystyles.scss';

//Routes
import DynamicLayout from './layout/DynamicLayout'
import FrontpageRoute from './routes/FrontpageRoute';
import BookRoute from './routes/BookRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">        
        <Switch>
          <DynamicLayout 
              exact 
              path="/" 
              component={FrontpageRoute} 
          />

          <DynamicLayout 
              exact 
              path="/book" 
              component={BookRoute} 
              layout="SUB_NAV" 
          />

        </Switch>        
      </div>
    </Router>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my DynamicLayoutRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './../components/Header';
import MainNavigation from '../components/MainNavigation';

const DynamicLayout = props => {
  const { component: RoutedComponent, layout, ...rest } = props;
  
    const actualRouteComponent = (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => (
           <RoutedComponent {...props} />
        )}
      />
    );
    switch (layout) {
      case 'MAIN_NAV': {
        return (
          <div>
            <MainNavigation />
            <Header />
            {actualRouteComponent}
          </div>
        )
      }
      case 'SUB_NAV': {
        return (
          <div>
            <MainNavigation />
            <h2>Sub Nav</h2>
            <Header />
            {actualRouteComponent}
          </div>
        )
      }
      default: {
        return (
          <div>
            <MainNavigation />
            <Header />
            {actualRouteComponent}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  };    

  export default DynamicLayout;
```

and here is my MainNavigation.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

class MainNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="main-navigation"> 
                <div className="main-navigation--content"> 
                    <div className="mobil-nav">
                        <span>Burger</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className="link-list">       
                        <NavLink exact to="/">Frontpage</NavLink>
                        <NavLink exact to="/book">Book</NavLink>   
                    </div>   

                    <div className="social">
                        <span>Instagram</span>
                    </div>        
                    
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default MainNavigation
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Did the error message give you a line number and stacktrace to review?

Comment: There is no error messages, it just dont show the "actualRouteComponent"

Comment: You initially had a `cannot access props of undefined` error, I was trying to point out that generally errors tell you right where the error occurs and provide a callstack so you can trace back what was called.

Comment: Sorry, Arphita solved part of the question, so i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your `DynamicLayoutRoute` component you are accessing props as `this.props`. `this` is undefined in functional components.

Access props like this -

```
const DynamicLayoutRoute = props => {
  const { component: RoutedComponent, layout, ...rest } = props;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Now i can switch pages and the different nav is showing up - but the component for the route is not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this so that we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: Im sorry - im not sure how to do this. React is new to me :/ It is like the "actualRouteComponent" is not working?

Comment: If anyone face the same problems i solved this by changing the actualRouteComponent to const actualRouteComponent = (
      <RoutedComponent {...props} />
    );